# Как оставить меню открытым при переходе на другую страницу?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть следующее меню:

```
<div class="nav_link">
    <div class="nav_link_text">
        <div id="sweeties" class="menu"> <span id="sweeties-title" class="title">???????? (????? ????)!</span>

            <ul>
                <li>????</li>
                <li>??????</li>
                <li>????????</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    var titleElem = document.getElementById('sweeties-title');

    titleElem.onclick = function () {
        var menu = this.parentNode
        if (hasClass(menu, 'menu-open')) {
            removeClass(menu, 'menu-open');
        } else {
            addClass(menu, 'menu-open');
        }
    }


    // -------------- helpers --------------
    function addClass(el, cls) {
        for (var c = el.className.split(' '), i = c.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (c[i] == cls) return;
        }
        if (el.className == "") el.className = cls
        else el.className += ' ' + cls
    }

    function hasClass(el, cls) {
        for (var c = el.className.split(' '), i = c.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (c[i] == cls) return true;
        }
    }

    function removeClass(el, cls) {
        for (var c = el.className.split(' '), i = c.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (c[i] == cls) c.splice(i, 1);
        }

        el.className = c.join(' ');
    }
</script>
```

Как можно сделать так, что пользователь открывает меню, переходит по внутреннему пункту, и на новой странице меню не закрывается, а остаётся открытым?

Как сделать меню открывающимся, решено.

Но почему-то при переходе на другую страницу меню закрывается.

Код первой страницы:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

<div class="nav_link">
    <div class="nav_link_text">
        <div id="sweeties" class="menu"> <span id="sweeties-title" class="title">???????? (????? ????)!</span>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">????</a></li>
                <li><a href="1.html">??????</a></li>
                <li>????????</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    var titleElem = document.getElementById('sweeties-title');
    var menu = titleElem.parentNode;

    if(localStorage.getItem('menu') != undefined && localStorage.getItem('menu') == true) {
         addClass(menu, 'menu-open');
    }

    titleElem.onclick = function () {

        if (hasClass(menu, 'menu-open')) {
            localStorage.setItem('menu', false); // false - закрыт
            removeClass(menu, 'menu-open');
        } else {
            localStorage.setItem('menu', true); //  true - открыт
            addClass(menu, 'menu-open');
        }
    }

    // -------------- helpers --------------
    function addClass(el, cls) {
        for (var c = el.className.split(' '), i = c.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (c[i] == cls) return;
        }
        if (el.className == "") el.className = cls
        else el.className += ' ' + cls
    }

    function hasClass(el, cls) {
        for (var c = el.className.split(' '), i = c.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (c[i] == cls) return true;
        }
    }

    function removeClass(el, cls) {
        for (var c = el.className.split(' '), i = c.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (c[i] == cls) c.splice(i, 1);
        }

        el.className = c.join(' ');
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Код второй страницы:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

<div class="nav_link">
    <div class="nav_link_text">
        <div id="sweeties" class="menu"> <span id="sweeties-title" class="title">???????? (????? ????)!</span>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">????</a></li>
                <li><a href="1.html">??????</a></li>
                <li>????????</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    var titleElem = document.getElementById('sweeties-title');
    var menu = titleElem.parentNode;

    if(localStorage.getItem('menu') != undefined && localStorage.getItem('menu') == true) {
         addClass(menu, 'menu-open');
    }

    titleElem.onclick = function () {

        if (hasClass(menu, 'menu-open')) {
            localStorage.setItem('menu', false); // false - закрыт
            removeClass(menu, 'menu-open');
        } else {
            localStorage.setItem('menu', true); //  true - открыт
            addClass(menu, 'menu-open');
        }
    }

    // -------------- helpers --------------
    function addClass(el, cls) {
        for (var c = el.className.split(' '), i = c.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (c[i] == cls) return;
        }
        if (el.className == "") el.className = cls
        else el.className += ' ' + cls
    }

    function hasClass(el, cls) {
        for (var c = el.className.split(' '), i = c.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (c[i] == cls) return true;
        }
    }

    function removeClass(el, cls) {
        for (var c = el.className.split(' '), i = c.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (c[i] == cls) c.splice(i, 1);
        }

        el.className = c.join(' ');
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @laboomba почитайте этот топик: http://forum.woweb.ru/topic51645.html

Comment: а как это всё внедрить в представленный код? Скажите пожалуйста!

Comment: @laboomba ну для начала вы попробуйте что-нибудь сами придумать, а уж мы поможем довести до ума!

Comment: Да уж и придумать ничего не могу. Подскажите, пожалуйста!

Comment: lampa, а как этим отладчиком пользоваться? Что там нужно смотреть?

Comment: А как держать в localstorage ассоциативный массив типа value=key, чтобы все пункты меню работали?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
<div class="nav_link">
    <div class="nav_link_text">
        <div id="sweeties" class="menu"> <span id="sweeties-title" class="title">???????? (????? ????)!</span>

            <ul>
                <li>????</li>
                <li>??????</li>
                <li>????????</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    var titleElem = document.getElementById('sweeties-title');
    var menu = titleElem.parentNode;

    if(localStorage.getItem('menu') != undefined && localStorage.getItem('menu') == true) {
         addClass(menu, 'menu-open');
    }

    titleElem.onclick = function () {

        if (hasClass(menu, 'menu-open')) {
            localStorage.setItem('menu', false); // false - закрыт
            removeClass(menu, 'menu-open');
        } else {
            localStorage.setItem('menu', true); //  true - открыт
            addClass(menu, 'menu-open');
        }
    }

    // -------------- helpers --------------
    function addClass(el, cls) {
        for (var c = el.className.split(' '), i = c.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (c[i] == cls) return;
        }
        if (el.className == "") el.className = cls
        else el.className += ' ' + cls
    }

    function hasClass(el, cls) {
        for (var c = el.className.split(' '), i = c.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (c[i] == cls) return true;
        }
    }

    function removeClass(el, cls) {
        for (var c = el.className.split(' '), i = c.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (c[i] == cls) c.splice(i, 1);
        }

        el.className = c.join(' ');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Почему-то у меня не работает

Comment: Ошибся в var menu = this.parentNode; вместо this нужно подставить titleElem. Пост обновил.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Всё работает. Но возник вопрос. Если я размещаю больше одного пункта меню, которое открывается, то нифига не работает. Как это можно исправить? Я могу поменять имена переменных, но так как сайт динамический и пункты меню выводятся циклом, то сделать этого просто не могу.

Comment: @laboomba вам нужно просто держать в localstorage ассоциативный массив типа value=key, в котором будет содержаться все значения для всех меню. Но это уже ведь немного другая задача, т.к. код не соответствует вашему описанию.

Comment: Кстати. Не работает почему-то тот код, который вы представили.

Comment: На одной страничке, где была только менюшка, работало (я просто ссылку # сделал, и при обновлении меню оставалось открытым). А в меню на сайте, где реальная ссылка, уже не работает.

Comment: Код но написанию вполне должен работать. Скорее всего при переносе допущена ошибка. Советую поставить какой-нибудь отладчик в браузер и посмотреть ответ. Сам пользуюсь браузером firefox и отладчиком для этого браузера - firebug.

Answer (score 1):

А вы сайт на CMS сажаете? Например, я знаю что Joomla добавляет класс active активному пункту меню. Ну а найти в меню пункт с таким классом и сделать его открытым не сложно.

Comment: Нет. Не на CMS. Самописная.